How can you generate possible permutations from a given string in tsql where you need multiple replace() calls for specific characters?
I have a column that contains license plates. The plate data somes from multiple sources and is not completely accurate. I must assume that zero's are misinterpreted as 'O' and vice versa. This includes multiple varying results in the same plate (OCR says 00OABC, when actual plate is 0O0ABC). To handle this, I need to build a where clause that uses all possible replacement values for every instance zero and the letter 'O'. How can this be done in tslq? Examples:
Plate, (where clause needed)

ABC012, (ABC012, ABCO12)
0OABC, (00ABC, OOABC, 0OABC, OOABC)
000XYZ, (000XYZ,00OXYZ,0OOXYZ,0O0XYZ,O00XYZ,O0OXYZ,OOOXYZ,OO0XYZ)

Edit: I need to build a where in clause, because I cannot do a replace in my select statement (example: select * from plates where replace(plate,'O','0') = '000XYZ'). I cannot do a replace because there is too much data. If this were a small table or if this were hadoop, it would be fine. What I have to work with is a MSSQL DB with a 20bn row table.

I can't talk for the country you reside in, but some (many?) countries have a format requirement for licence plates, meaning that a zero (0) cannot appear in a position that a letter (O) can appear. This then means you can apply validation to ensure that such characters aren't input incorrectly. Does that apply here as well? If so the ideally you should be addressing that problem (the quality of the data).

Alternatively, if the location you reside in doesn't have such rules, and it appears that 0 and O are interchangable, it would seem that it would be better to replace all instantances of one to the other, and not allow the other in the column; then you can't have a case of searching for the wrong letter/number (in a specific position).

And, of course, finally, if they aren't interchangable, and 0 and O mean different things, then you shouldn't be doing this, and you shouldn't be returning the value 000ABC when searching OOOABC, as they are different values.

@ThomA thank you for your thoughts, but I am not in control of any of the inputs. The plates are from multiple OCR systems, and some produce wild results. I have a dataset that includes zeros that are misread as O and vice versa. I even have examples where a plate has two O's and one zero, and the O's are zeros and the zero is an O. I plan to in the future use a computed column in an index to help with this, but for now I need a simple replacement function to build a where clause. I just assume every permutation is possible for every occurrence of both zero and O.

If you don't care about performance, just REPLACE on both sides then. If you do, then the data is the issue, not the query.

Hm, my question might not be clear. A simple replace without come kind of function or nested loop will not give all the permutations I require. Let me see if I can ask the question in a better way.

So, is not for comparison purposes (in the WHERE) as your question suggests? A loop is a terrible idea, and likely worse performance that a non-SARGable REPLACE.

Replace all occurrences of zero with O on both sides and then compare the strings. That will cover all possible permutations in one swell foop. If there are special rules, e.g. the first character cannot be a digit, then they may need to be handled separately.

@ThomA any suggestions? Would you like to answer with some sample tsql queries?

I think you're still missing the easy answer. Pick a character to represent a pair (or larger set) of oft confused characters, e.g. use ¤ (currency symbol) for either 0 (zero) or O (uppercase o). If you have a set of possibly misread plates, e.g. FOO and F00, you can convert them to standard form F¤¤ by replacing all of the characters in the confounding set (0 and O) with one symbol. It doesn't matter whether someone introduces F0O or FO0, they all convert to the same standard form. As such, you can compare all permutations by comparing the standard form of each string. ...

... It can be extended to replace 1 (one) and I (uppercase i) with ! (exclamation point) and so on with other sets of easily confused characters. Instead of introducing new characters you can achieve the same result by converting all of the characters in a set to one character in the set, e.g. 1 and I all become I.

so vanity  and design plates are not an issue for you? you are strict to one mask. correct?

Thank you @HABO your solution is on the right track, but I am unable to do replace() on the select. I edited my question accordingly.

The solution to this problem revolves around defining character equivalences.
Just as case-insensitive compares treat uppercase letters as equivalent to the corresponding lowercase letters, and accent-insensitive comparisons will treat "à", "á", "â", and others as equivalent to "a", we need to define character equivalences for similar-looking characters.
Once we have done that, we can define functions for comparing plate numbers having similar appearances and to generate sets of similar appearing plates.
For comparisons, I believe that most case-insensitive and accent-insensitive compares will map equivalent characters to a preferred form (such as all accent-free lowercase) before doing the comparison. We can do the same by defining a translation of all alternate characters to their equivalent base or preferred forms before doing any comparison.
To generate sets of similar appearing plates, we can use a recursive CTE (common table expression) that steps through the plate number one character at a time, while mapping each character to all defined equivalent characters, including itself. Each character would be mapped independently, so the the final result includes all combinations (a cross product) of each character mapping.
I've put together some sample code as follows:
-- This table defines character mappings for similar looking characters.
-- The BaseChar value is considered the primary for each equivalence set,
-- while the AltChar values are the alternate characters that should be
-- considered to the base character and to any alternates sharing the same
-- base character.
CREATE TABLE PlateCharacterMap (
    BaseChar CHAR,  -- Source character from reader or database
    AltChar CHAR     -- Equivalent character for comparison purposes
)
INSERT PlateCharacterMap
VALUES
    ('O', '0'),
    ('I', '1'),
    ('S', '5'),
    ('O', 'Q')

-- Also map any defined base charcaters to themselves
-- to support later processing logic.
INSERT PlateCharacterMap
SELECT DISTINCT BaseChar, BaseChar
FROM PlateCharacterMap

To support direct compares between two potentially similar plate numbers, we need to define TranslateFrom and TranslateTo strings that can be used with the TRANSLATE() function.
-- This single-row table is used to define translations for comparing any two
-- plate numbers. All alternate characters will be mapped to their associated
-- base characters.
CREATE TABLE PlateTranslateStrings (
    TranslateFrom VARCHAR(1000),
    TranslateTo VARCHAR(1000)
)
INSERT PlateTranslateStrings
SELECT
    STRING_AGG(AltChar, '') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY AltChar) AS TranslateFrom,
    STRING_AGG(BaseChar, '') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY AltChar) AS TranslateTo
FROM PlateCharacterMap
WHERE AltChar <> BaseChar

The above would calculate TranslateFrom = '015Q' and TranslateTo = 'OISO'.
Functions for (1) plate number mapping, (2) plate number comparison, and (3) plate number permutations follow:
-- Map a plate number to a string suitable for fuzzy comparisons
CREATE FUNCTION PlateCompareString(@PlateNumber VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (
        SELECT TRANSLATE(@PlateNumber, T.TranslateFrom, T.TranslateTo)
        FROM PlateTranslateStrings T
    )
END

-- Perform a fuzzy comparison of plate numbers
CREATE FUNCTION PlateCompare(@Left VARCHAR(10), @Right VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CASE WHEN dbo.PlateCompareString(@Left) = dbo.PlateCompareString(@Right)
           THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
END

-- Generate a set of similar plates for a given plate number.
CREATE FUNCTION PlatePermutations(@PlateNumber VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
    WITH CTE_Permutate AS (
        -- Anchor - Seed with empty result.
        SELECT
            CAST('' AS VARCHAR(10)) AS Result,
            @PlateNumber AS Remaining
        UNION ALL
        -- Map next character to itself.
        SELECT
            CAST(P.Result + LEFT(P.Remaining, 1) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS Result,
            STUFF(P.Remaining, 1, 1, '') AS Remaining
        FROM CTE_Permutate P
        WHERE LEN(P.Remaining) > 0
        UNION ALL
        -- Also map next character to all characters sharing the same base character
        -- except itself.
        SELECT
            CAST(P.Result + ISNULL(M2.AltChar, LEFT(P.Remaining, 1)) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS Result,
            STUFF(P.Remaining, 1, 1, '') AS Remaining
        FROM CTE_Permutate P
        JOIN PlateCharacterMap M1 ON M1.AltChar = LEFT(P.Remaining, 1)
        JOIN PlateCharacterMap M2 ON M2.BaseChar = M1.BaseChar
        WHERE LEN(P.Remaining) > 0
        AND M2.AltChar <> M1.AltChar -- Exclude self (already included above)
    )
    SELECT P.Result AS PlatePermutation
    FROM CTE_Permutate P
    WHERE LEN(P.Remaining) = 0  -- Only include the completed mappings
)

Test code:
-- Plate comparison test
WITH CTE_TestData AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        VALUES
            ('ABC-XYZ'),
            ('ABC-OIS'), ('ABC-O15'), ('ABC-015'),
            ('PASSWORD'), ('PA55W0RD')
    ) V(PlateNumber)
)
SELECT
    P1.PlateNumber AS PlateNumber1,
    P2.PlateNumber AS PlateNumber2,
    dbo.PlateCompareString(P1.PlateNumber) AS CompareString1,
    dbo.PlateCompareString(P2.PlateNumber) AS CompareString2,
    CASE WHEN dbo.PlateCompare(P1.PlateNumber, P2.PlateNumber) = 1
         THEN 'Match' ELSE '' END AS Match 
FROM CTE_TestData P1
JOIN CTE_TestData P2
    ON P2.PlateNumber > P1.PlateNumber
ORDER BY P1.PlateNumber, P2.PlateNumber

Results:



PlateNumber1
PlateNumber2
CompareString1
CompareString2
Match




ABC-015
ABC-O15
ABC-OIS
ABC-OIS
Match


ABC-015
ABC-OIS
ABC-OIS
ABC-OIS
Match


ABC-015
ABC-XYZ
ABC-OIS
ABC-XYZ



ABC-015
PA55W0RD
ABC-OIS
PASSWORD



ABC-015
PASSWORD
ABC-OIS
PASSWORD



ABC-O15
ABC-OIS
ABC-OIS
ABC-OIS
Match


...
...
...
...
...


PA55W0RD
PASSWORD
PASSWORD
PASSWORD
Match



Plate permutation test:
-- Permutation demo
SELECT P.PlateNumber, PERM.PlatePermutation,
    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY P.PlateNumber) AS PermutationCount
FROM (
    VALUES
        ('A-ZZZ'),  -- just this one
        ('B-1'),    -- 2 permutations
        ('C-S'),    -- 2 permutations
        ('D-Q'),    -- 3 permutations
        ('E-15'),   -- 2 x 2 = 4 permutations
        ('F-ISQ'),  -- 2 x 2 x 3 = 12 permutations
        ('G-OQ0'),  -- 3 x 3 x 3 = 27 permutations
        ('H-O0Q15') -- 3 x 3 x 3 x 2 x 2 = 108 permutations
) P(PlateNumber)
CROSS APPLY dbo.PlatePermutations(P.PlateNumber) PERM
ORDER BY P.PlateNumber, PERM.PlatePermutation

Partial results:



PlateNumber
PlatePermutation
PermutationCount




A-ZZZ
A-ZZZ
1


B-1
B-1
2


B-1
B-I
2


C-S
C-5
2


C-S
C-S
2


D-Q
D-0
3


D-Q
D-O
3


D-Q
D-Q
3


E-15
E-15
4


E-15
E-1S
4


E-15
E-I5
4


E-15
E-IS
4


...
...
...



As for a WHERE clause for searches, you can use either the PlateCompare or PlatePermutations function. The former may be useful for individual compares, while the latter is better for searches
CREATE TABLE PlateDatabase (
    PlateNumber VARCHAR(10)
)
INSERT PlateDatabase
VALUES
    ('ABC-XYZ'),
    ('ABC-OIS'), ('ABC-O15'), ('ABC-015'),
    ('PASSWORD'), ('PA55W0RD')

SELECT *
FROM PlateDatabase P
WHERE dbo.PlateCompare(P.PlateNumber, 'PASSW0RD') = 1

SELECT *
FROM PlateDatabase P
WHERE P.PlateNumber IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.PlatePermutations('ABC-OI5'))

SELECT P.*
FROM dbo.PlatePermutations('ABC-OI5') PERM
JOIN PlateDatabase P ON P.PlateNumber = PERM.PlatePermutation

I expect the latter would have the best performance, since the join will likely involve an index seek (assuming that PlateNumber is indexed).
Results (the last queries above have the same results):



PlateNumber




PASSWORD


PA55W0RD






PlateNumber




ABC-OIS


ABC-O15


ABC-015



See this db<>fiddle for a demo of everything discussed above.
This may not be the best and final answer, but should get you pretty close. I added a couple of extra equivalences to the initial mapping. You can of course tailor these mappings to your specifications.
SQL server databases typically are defined with a case-insensitive collation by default. Because I believe plate numbers typically only use uppercase letters, I did not go out of my way to override that default collation.

This is a huge help. Thank you.

Just fixed a spelling error in the code "Permiate" -> "Permutate".  Even so, somewhere out there is a mathematician screeming "this is not a permutation it is a combination" or some other more accurate math term.
